# how do I set up the following thread in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a thread with the following form:

1. each execution of each thread is supposed to run a function in the class. That function is completely safe to run by itself. The function returns a value, say an int.
2. After all threads have been executed, the function values need to be accumulated.

So, it goes (in pseudo-code) something like that:

```
  a = 0
  for each i between 1 to N
      spawn a thread independently and call the command v = f(i)
      when thread finishes, do safely: a = a + v
  end
```

I am not sure how to use Java in that case.

The problem is not creating the thread, I know this can be done using

```
new Thread() { 
   public void run() { 
     ... 
   } 
}
```

the problem is accumulating all the answers.

Thanks for any info.

Comment: Not much experience with Java, but I suggest checking out the ForkJoin stuff from Java.. 7? I think it is. Try this: http://www.infoq.com/news/2008/03/fork_join

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would probably do something like:

```
 public class Main {
     int a = 0;
     int[] values;
     int[] results;

     public Main() {
         // Init values array

         results = new int[N];
     }

     public int doStuff() {
         LinkedList<Thread> threads = new LinkedList<Thread>();

         for (final int i : values) {
             Thread t = new Thread() {
                 public void run() {
                     accumulate(foo(i));
                 }
             };

             threads.add(t);
             t.start();
          }

          for (Thread t : threads) {
              try {
                  t.join();
              } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                  // Act accordingly, maybe ignore?
              }
          }

          return a;
     }

     synchronized void accumulate(int v) {
          // Synchronized because a += v is actually
          //    tmp = a + v;
          //    a = tmp;
          // which can cause a race condition AFAIK
          a += v;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Your idea is good. Remember to code oriented to interfaces, use `List<Thread> threads = new ClassThatImplementsList<Thread>();` instead of declaring `LinkedList`.

Answer (score 3):

Use an `ExecutorCompletionService`, `Executor`, and `Callable`.:

Start with a `Callable` that calls your `int` function:

```
public class MyCallable implements Callable<Integer> {
    private final int i;

    public MyCallable(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    public Integer call() {
        return Integer.valueOf(myFunction(i));
    }
}
```

Create an `Executor`:

```
private final Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
```

`10` is the maximum number of threads to execute at once.

Then wrap it in an `ExecutorCompletionService` and submit your jobs:

```
CompletionService<Integer> compService = new ExecutionCompletionService<Integer>(executor);

// Make sure to track the number of jobs you submit
int jobCount;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    compService.submit(new MyCallable(i));
    jobCount++;
}

// Get the results
int a = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < jobCount; i++) {
    a += compService.take().get().intValue();
}
```

`ExecutorCompletionService` allows you to pull tasks off of a queue as they complete. This is a little different from joining threads. Although the overall outcome is the same, if you want to update a UI as the threads complete, you won't know what order the threads are going to complete using a join. That last `for` loop could be like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < jobCount; i++) {
    a += compService.take().get().intValue();
    updateUi(a);
}
```

And this will update the UI as tasks complete. Using a `Thread.join` won't necessarily do this since you'll be getting the results in the order that you call the joins, *not* the order that the threads complete.

Through the use of the executor, this will also allow you to limit the number of simultaneous jobs you're running at a given time so you don't accidentally thread-bomb your system.

Comment: Of course, if you don't need to update anything besides `a` in your code, then using `Thread.join` is fine :)